# Loop though hosts using Jinja2 template

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2

I have hosts file like below

```
[test1]
10.33.11.198
10.33.11.185
```

i am using a template like below

```
{% for i in groups['test1'] %}
IP{{ i }}={{ hostvars[groups['test1'][i]]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

my expectation is

```
IP0=10.33.11.198
IP1=10.33.11.185
```

but, i am getting below error.

```
fatal: [10.33.11.198]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'list object' has no attribute u'10.33.11.198'"}
fatal: [10.33.11.185]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'list object' has no attribute u'10.33.11.198'"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that i is not an index, but an element of the list.
Try

```
{% for i in groups['test1'] %}
IP{{ loop.index0 }}={{ hostvars[i]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Check [Jinja2 for statement](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#list-of-control-structures)

Trying a minimal example:

hosts:

```
[test1]
10.33.11.198
10.33.11.185
```

and x.yml (replaced your `['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']` with just `inventory_hostname`)

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - debug: msg="{% for i in groups['test1'] %}\nIP{{ loop.index0 }}={{ hostvars[i].inventory_hostname }}\n{% endfor %}"
```

running:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts x.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "IP0=10.33.11.198\nIP1=10.33.11.185\n"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```